# how to select multiple images using react-native-image-crop-picker in react-native

Tags: react-native, file-upload, android-image, react-native-image-picker

android not support selecting multiple images using react-native-image-crop-picker , how to fixed it ?

```
enter code here
```

`        handlePickImage = async () => {
        try {

```
        console.log('hit')
        const images = await ImagePicker.openPicker({
            width: 1000,
            height: 1000,
            cropping: true,
            multiple: true,
            compressImageQuality: 0.5,

        })
        console.log(images)

        for (const image of images) {
            const path = image.path.split('/');
            const fileName = path[path.length - 1]
            console.log('fileNameforVideo', fileName)
            this.setState(
                {
                    files: [... this.state.files, { url: '', type: image.mime.split('/')[0], path: image.path }],
                    file: image.path,
                    fileName,
                    filetype: image.mime.split('/')[0],
                    mimeType: image.mime
                })


            await this.getSingedUrl();
        }

    } catch (error) {

        console.log(error)
        console.log('lol')
    }
```

`
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Currently, it is possible in the following ways.

```js
ImagePicker.openPicker({
            multiple: true,
            compressImageQuality: 0.5,

        }).then(async images => {
        const result = [];

        for await (const image of images) {
            const img = await ImagePicker.openCropper({
                mediaType: "photo",
                path: image.path,
                width: 1000,
                height: 1000,
            });
            result.push(img.path);
        }

        return result;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand correctly the issue you are experiencing, but the library you are using has a note in their docs that says:

> "Android: The prop 'cropping' has been known to cause videos not to be display in the gallery on Android. Please do not set cropping to true when selecting videos."

(link to the library README [here](https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker))

You seem to be setting the `multiple` option correctly, but I noticed you have cropping set to `true`, which may be the cause of your issue. I hope that helps!